# How to tell the browser to ignore previous css edits?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I like what twitter has done with bootstrap css, except for their resetting the fieldset and legend tags.

Q: Short of cutting those definitions out of bootstrap.css, is there a way to tell the browser to ignore those commands?

The reason why I don't want to change bootstrap.css is in case they update it some time in the future, I might not remember to go back in and say "Everything is good except for these 2 definitions".

Comment: Maybe I could remove them from the DOM using JavaScript?

Comment: after loading bootstrap css, set the css for fieldset and legend to match your desired formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just redefine it to what you want below the bootstrap.css definitions. Later css always overrides early css (assuming the `!important` flag is not set on the earlier).

So:

```
legend {color: red;} /*pretend this is bootstrap's definition*/

legend {color: green;}
```

will produce green text.

**NOTE:** you do need to be aware of css specificity. Class and ID's and other such css can make the definition more specific, so to override it, later css must have equal or greater specificity.

```
.box legend {color: red;} /*pretend this is bootstrap's definition*/

legend {color: green;}
```

Would produce red text *if the `legend` is in a `box` classed element* because of the higher specificity of the `.box` class. You would need to at least match that specificity:

```
.box legend {color: green;}
```

Comment: Must you redfine all of what bootstrap defines for legend if you just want to use a couple styles and ignore the rest of bootstraps?      -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-image: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color #E5E5E5;
    border-style: none none solid;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    font-size: 19.5px;
    line-height: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 27px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;